# How to Deploy Model Update in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net in general and inherited an ASP.Net MVC Web site and need to make a change to a Model class file. My question is, how do I deploy that single change? I take it that I have to make the change, rebuild the solution and then move over the main application .dll file but not the .cs file, is all that correct?  That is, the source code change will get rolled into the main application .dll so there is no need to move over the class file as well. Do I understand all that correctly?

Comment: i dont think you can update the model separately. you build and upload the dll.

Comment: @PrashanthBenny thanks for the response. Just so I am clear, I make the change, rebuild and then move the main .dll file over, correct? I see a .dll file named <my_app_name>.dll on production and I assume that is where the Model changed will be compiled into, is that correct?

Comment: exactly. that includes all the changes in the models and controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# is compiled so yes, you are correct in that you need to build the project and then deploy the DLL.